# How can I get a simple code which is not going to be repeated?

Tags: sql, asp.net, vb.net, vbscript, asp-classic

I need to create a code number for the ID of a SQL Database table, I'm working on an application programmed by vb.net and another one programmed by vbscript. Both of them are connected to a database and I need to generate a code number in each one which has to be generated by the same procedure. For example:

**VB.NET:**

```
dim code as integer= someFunction()
```

**VBScript:**

```
dim code= call someFunction()
```

I want the functions to generate the same kind of code but in different languages.

Comment: Sorry, this is not clear to me. By which conditions should the generated number be the same?

Comment: I don't need the codes to be the same,  I need them to be created in the same way.@Galcoholic

Comment: use an `identity` column in your database as either the primary key or with  unique  constraint https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-transact-sql-identity-property

Comment: Thanks @SSS but I need to create the code number in the application, not in th database.

Comment: Without any requirement on the code (format, etc.) I would say a return 123456 will do in any language. Stupid answer, but this question is quite fuzzy...

Comment: I am just asking for a code number which is not going to be repeated, those are the requirements. @Galcoholic

Comment: But why do you need to go out from the database? You could use a simple DB sequence to generate individual numbers.

Comment: Unless you can provide a reason that the IDs should not be generated by the database then generated by the database they should be.  If there is a good reason to generate them outside the database then the easiest option may be to use a GUID.  In VB.NET, you can use the `Guid.NewGuid` method to generate a GUID.  I don;t know how it would be done in VBScript but I'd imagine that there's a way.  They can be stored in SQL Server in a column of type `uniqueidentifier`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are really intent on doing this, you can implement the same functionality from VBS in VB.NET:

VB.NET

```
    Dim tlib = CreateObject("Scriptlet.TypeLib")
    Messagebox.Show(tlib.Guid)
```

VBScript:

```
    Dim tlib
    set tlib = CreateObject("Scriptlet.TypeLib")
    MsgBox(tlib.Guid)
```